# what function follows $f(z)=f(z^2+1)=-if(z^2+i)$ and $f(z)$ isn't a constant.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

what function follows $f(z)=f(z^2+1)=-if(z^2+i)$ and $f(z)$ isn't a constant. I'm assuming it is analytic.

The first thing I tried was to take the derivative of $f(z)$

I found that $f'(x)=2zf'(z^2+1)=-i2zf'(z^2+i)$

I took $2zf'(z^2+1)$ and $-i2zf'(z^2+i)$ into $2zh(t+1)$ and $-i2zh(t+i)$ by changing $z^2$ into t

I divided both sides by $2z$ to get $h(t+1)=-ih(t+i)$

then subtracted $1$ on both sides $h(t)=-ih(t-(1-i))$

I'm not sure what to do from here. If you could give me any tips on what to do next that would help.

Comment: You can't take derivative since you don't know if $f$ is differentiable or not. You simply have $f(t)=-if(t+i-1)$ by letting $t=z^2+1$.

Comment: @xpaul oh I'm assuming it is differentiable you might be right it might not be.

Comment: I doubt that such non-zero constant function exists. If $f(z)=C$, a constant, then you have $C=-iC$ which gives $C=0$ or $f(z)=0$.

Comment: @xpaul $f(z)$ isn't a constant. If it has to be 0 could you show that?

Comment: You have to assume that $f$ is analytic.

Comment: @xpaul Differentiable is analytic. Here I guess continuity suffices, as it should be possible to show that $f$ vanishes on a dense subset of $\Bbb C$. But giving a rigorous proof seems to be annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only entire function such that $f(z) = -i f(z^2+i)$ is $0$.

Suppose $f$ was such a function.
Let $p$ and $q$ be the two roots of $z = z^2 + i$, so $z^2 - z + i = (z-p)(z-q)$.  Then $f(p) = -i f(p)$ so $f(p) = 0$.
Suppose the first nonzero term in the Taylor series of $f$ about $p$ is $c_k (z-p)^k$.
Thus $f(z) \sim c_k (z-p)^k$ as $z \to p$.  Then also
$f(z^2 + i) \sim c_k (z^2+i-p)^k$, but $z^2 + i - p = (z-p)(z-q+1) \sim (p-q+1)(z-p)$ as $z \to p$, so $f(z^2+i) \sim c_k (p-q+1)^k (z-p)^k$.  But $-if(z^2+i) = f(z)$ so
this can only work if $-i (p-q+1)^k = 1$.  However, $|p-q+1| > 1$ so this is impossible.